# Entity Framework + Repository + Unit of Work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository, unit-of-work

I'm thinking about starting a new project using EF 4 and going through some articles, I found some articles about EF with repository pattern and unit of work

( http://tdryan.blogspot.com/2011/03/another-entity-framework-4-repository_15.html and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx)

I'm using the first one (part1, part2 and part3). They are very similar.

I'm a newbie in this scenario. I'm confusing between these two posts. I've create everything but I have no idea how can I start using the context and add some entities to it. I posted the second link because posted a way to implement it. The `ObjectContext` is derived from `IUnitOfWork`, so I'm confused to chose which of these two is better to use.

Answer (score 32):

Your question is not stupid! Getting started with `UnitOfWork` and the `Repository` patterns takes some time.

First, to get some terminoloy right. A `UnitOfWork` encapsulates a set of actions and groups them together. So you can for example create a customer, a product and a corresponding order in one logical group.

A `Repository` gives you a single point of access to entities and most of the time has some specific methods for retrieving data.

Multiple repositories can be used in one single transaction, that's why they share a `UnitOfWork`.

In the example you posted, the T4 files create some `Repository` interfaces. One is a readonly with methods to select entities but the other `Repository` has methods like `Add` and `Delete`.

So if you want to add an entity, you need to first construct a `UnitOfWork` and then instantiate a `Repository` for the entity type your working with (`CustomerRepository` or `ProductRepository` for example). You can then use the `Add` method to add entities to a `Repository`. When you're done working with your repositories you would call `UnitOfWork.Commit()` to save your changes to the database.

```
IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new EFUnitOfWork();

IRepository<Customer> customerRepository = new CustomerEFRepository(unitOfWork);

Customer c = new Customer();

// init customer

customerRepository.Add(c);
unitOfWork.Commit();
```

In the example you posted, Dependency Injection with StructureMap is used. This is a whole other topic, but it means that you don't construct the `UnitOfWork` and `Repository` directly but that they are 'injected' into your code using some configuration that you've setup.

Comment: I've been working on my own C# Repo/Unit of Work pattern for a while and I've always wondered if it was right. This is exactly how I've done it using Ninject injecting the uow and repositories into mvc controllers. My unitofwork holds a copy of the DbContext class that is shared with the repos.Thought you explained it well :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your project is web make a handler that start a transaction on a request and end it at the last step.

I think a much simpler example can be found here: https://github.com/ayende/CourseSampleApp
Also you can find other samples on nhibernate which can satisfy your need.